# How to find the difference of elements within an array of 0 and 1

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I currently have this array.

```
idx_binary = array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I'm trying to find all the instances where the difference between two elements in this array is 1 (so when it goes from 0 to 1).

This is what I currently have for that:

```
threshCross_idx = np.where(np.diff(idx_binary) == 1)
```

However, this is giving me all the instances of 1 ((array([48], dtype=int64))). Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing incorrectly? I'd expect the output to be 1, since there's only one instance where the difference between two elements is 1.

Comment: it is not saying that there are 48 ones, it is saying that the single 1 is in position 48

Comment: wow, silly me. Thanks for that.